# Can't get the value of a function inside an object using socketIO with redux-toolkit

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, socket.io, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit with socket io but can't get the value return from the server. I try to assign the value into the res Array but the array length is still 0

```
    let res = []
    socket.emit("users")
    socket.on("users", (users) => 
    {
        res.concat(users)
        users.forEach(user => {
            const { username, userID} = user
            res.push({ username: username, userID: userID} )
        })
    })
    return res;
})
The array length is equal 0 but it's look like this 
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0KdF.png
```

Answer (score 0):

this emit function `socket.emit("users")`, didnt pass any users data for `socket.on("users", (users) => { //some code })`.

while doing `socket.emit("user")` you have to pass data to the function so that on event callback have it as a first arguement of the function. so the emite function would be like this `socket.emit("users", userData)` here `userData` is variable containing array of users

Comment: Actually on the server side I already send the value. If you see the images with the link on my question the res array is assign with some strange value but not inside the array

Comment: https://socket.io/get-started/private-messaging-part-1/ I'm doing this tut but with react instead of Vue in Vue they assign the variable with initReactiveProperties(user)
`socket.on("users", (users) => {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    user.self = user.userID === socket.id;
    initReactiveProperties(user);
  });
  // put the current user first, and then sort by username
  this.users = users.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.self) return -1;
    if (b.self) return 1;
    if (a.username < b.username) return -1;
    return a.username > b.username ? 1 : 0;
  });
});`